# Android Studio where does the Component Installer download to and is it possible to save the files

Tags: android-studio, installation, components

As per the title, with Android Studio installed on multiple machines, is it possible to avoid having the Component Installer having to download the files on each machine. Currently waiting while the 7GB of component updates downloads for the second time and I've a third machine to do after this. Where are the files stored and does the Component Installer delete them after? And is there a way of managing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloaded files are stored in to c:/users/user name of your pc/AppData/local/Android/SDK

Note: AppData is intially hidden open hidden file and folder then try